# regular expressions to remove repeated strings

Tags: r, regex

```
s <- "height (female), weight, BRCA1, height (female), BRCA1, weight, body mass index, body mass index, weight, weight, height (e.g. by kilos), body mass index." 

> unique(strsplit(s, ",")[[1]])
[1] "height (female)"         " weight"                 " BRCA1"                  " height (female)"        " body mass index"        " height (e.g. by kilos)"      " body mass index."
```

I have a string that has the following structure: `<string>, <string>, <string>, ..., <string>.`

Each `<string>` is separated by a comma, except the last one, which is followed by a period. I want to remove the duplicated strings using regular expressions. A string can take on one of the following three formats:

1. word followed by `(...)`, e.g. `height (female)` or `height (e.g. by kilos)`
2. a single word: e.g. `weight` or `BRCA1`
3. multiple words separated by a space, e.g. `body mass index`

My desired output is:

```
"height (female), weight, BRCA1, body mass index, height (e.g. by kilos)."
```

Simply doing a `strsplit` on the comma doesn't account for the special cases where there is a space right before the second occurrence of `height (female)` or when the last `body mass index` is followed by a period.

Comment: `strsplit` takes regular expressions too - `unique(strsplit(s, ",\\s+|\\.$")[[1]])` is nearly there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't have to escape any commas in the input, and the format is known (e.g. the string ends with a period that should be stripped), this can be done in a few simple steps:

```
library(stringr)
s_unique = s %>%
    str_remove("\\.$") %>%
    str_split(",", simplify = TRUE) %>%
    str_trim() %>%  # Trim whitespace
    unique()

paste0(s_unique, collapse = ", ")
```

Output:

```
[1] "height (female), weight, BRCA1, body mass index, height (e.g. by kilos)"
```

Answer (score 3):

@thelatemail's comment has you pointed in the right direction. Use `unlist(strsplit(x = <input string>, split = <regex pattern>))` to pull out the comma and space. `unique` pulls out the duplicates, and `paste(<character vector>, collapse = ", ")` puts everything back together. Don't forget to `unlist`, or unique will look for different elements of the list rather than the character vector.

```
# input
s <- "height (female), weight, BRCA1, height (female), BRCA1, weight, body mass index, body mass index, weight, weight, height (e.g. by kilos), body mass index." 

# code
paste(unique(unlist(strsplit(s, ",\\s+|\\.$"))), collapse = ", ")
# [1] "height (female), weight, BRCA1, body mass index, height (e.g. by kilos)"
```